# Let X be a linear space, why is the dual space of X a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a linear space, why is the dual space of X a Banach space? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: If $Y$ is Banach and $X$ is normed, the space of bounded linear functionals $L(X,Y)$ is always Banach.

Comment: It is not so, in general. So not "seeing why it is" is very reasonable. Still, ... context?

Comment: Because if $\phi_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X^{*}$ then $\phi_n (x)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the base field, which is complete.You can then prove that $\phi_n$ converges in $X^{*}$

Comment: @paulgarrett It is, because $\mathbb R$ is Banach. =)

Comment: If $X$ does not come with a norm what do you mean by the dual? Which norm there?

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you how to set it up.  If you need more assistance, let me know and I will edit.

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X^*$ (the dual space of $X$).  Then for each $x\in X$, $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the scalar field, and hence convergent (because both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are complete metric spaces).  Now define the function $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ by
$$ f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$

Now we need to show two things.

(i) $f\in X^*$ (i.e. $f$ is linear and bounded)

(ii) $f_n\to f$ in norm (i.e. $\|f_n-f\|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$).